# Mongodb aggregation-framework queries performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I'm using the aggregation framework of MongoDB to make multiple queries to have statistics about some played matches.
It worked great but now that I have 100k+ documents in my database the queries are really slow.

Each query take 1300ms to 3900ms. So my entire page takes about 12s to display.

Here is the code of the queries:

```js
class MatchRepository {
  static get inject() {
    return ['App/Models/Match']
  }

  constructor(Match) {
    this.Match = Match
  }

  /**
   * Basic matchParams used in a lot of requests
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   */
  _matchParams(puuid) {
    return {
      summoner_puuid: puuid,
      result: { $not: { $eq: 'Remake' } },
      gamemode: { $nin: [800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850] },
      season: this.season ? this.season : { $exists: true }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Build the aggregate mongo query
   * @param {Number} puuid 
   * @param {Object} matchParams 
   * @param {Array} intermediateSteps 
   * @param {*} groupId 
   * @param {Object} groupParams 
   * @param {Array} finalSteps 
   */
  _aggregate(puuid, matchParams, intermediateSteps, groupId, groupParams, finalSteps) {
    return this.Match.query().aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          ...this._matchParams(puuid),
          ...matchParams
        }
      },
      ...intermediateSteps,
      {
        $group: {
          _id: groupId,
          count: { $sum: 1 },
          wins: {
            $sum: {
              $cond: [{ $eq: ['$result', 'Win'] }, 1, 0]
            }
          },
          losses: {
            $sum: {
              $cond: [{ $eq: ['$result', 'Fail'] }, 1, 0]
            }
          },
          ...groupParams
        },
      },
      ...finalSteps
    ])
  }

  /**
   * Get Summoner's statistics for the N most played champions
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   * @param limit number of champions to fetch
   */
  championStats(puuid, limit = 5) {
    const groupParams = {
      champion: { $first: '$champion' },
      kills: { $sum: '$stats.kills' },
      deaths: { $sum: '$stats.deaths' },
      assists: { $sum: '$stats.assists' },
    }
    const finalSteps = [
      { $sort: { 'count': -1, 'champion.name': 1 } },
      { $limit: limit }
    ]
    return this._aggregate(puuid, {}, [], '$champion.id', groupParams, finalSteps)
  }

  /**
   * Get Summoner's statistics for all played champion classes
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   */
  championClassStats(puuid) {
    const groupId = { '$arrayElemAt': ['$champion.roles', 0] }
    return this._aggregate(puuid, {}, [], groupId, {}, [])
  }

  /**
   * Get Summoner's statistics for all played modes
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   */
  gamemodeStats(puuid) {
    return this._aggregate(puuid, {}, [], '$gamemode', {}, [])
  }

  /**
   * Get global Summoner's statistics
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   */
  globalStats(puuid) {
    const groupParams = {
      time: { $sum: '$time' },
      kills: { $sum: '$stats.kills' },
      deaths: { $sum: '$stats.deaths' },
      assists: { $sum: '$stats.assists' },
      minions: { $sum: '$stats.minions' },
      vision: { $sum: '$stats.vision' },
      kp: { $avg: '$stats.kp' },
    }
    return this._aggregate(puuid, {}, [], null, groupParams, [])
  }

  /**
   * Get Summoner's statistics for the 5 differnt roles
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   */
  roleStats(puuid) {
    const matchParams = {
      role: { $not: { $eq: 'NONE' } }
    }
    const finalSteps = [
      {
        $project: {
          role: '$_id',
          count: '$count',
          wins: '$wins',
          losses: '$losses',
        }
      }
    ]
    return this._aggregate(puuid, matchParams, [], '$role', {}, finalSteps)
  }
  /**
   * Get Summoner's played seasons
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   */
  seasons(puuid) {
    this.season = null

    return this.Match.query().aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          ...this._matchParams(puuid),
        }
      },
      {
        $group: { _id: '$season' }
      },
    ])
  }

  /**
   * Get Summoner's mates list
   * @param puuid of the summoner
   */
  mates(puuid) {
    const intermediateSteps = [
      { $sort: { 'gameId': -1 } },
      { $unwind: '$allyTeam' },
    ]
    const groupParams = {
      account_id: { $first: '$account_id' },
      name: { $first: '$allyTeam.name' },
      mateId: { $first: '$allyTeam.account_id' },
    }
    const finalSteps = [
      {
        '$addFields': {
          'idEq': { '$eq': ['$mateId', '$account_id'] }
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          'idEq': false,
          'count': { $gte: 2 }
        },
      },
      { $sort: { 'count': -1, 'name': 1 } },
      { $limit: 15 },
    ]
    return this._aggregate(puuid, {}, intermediateSteps, '$allyTeam.account_id', groupParams, finalSteps)
  }
}

module.exports = MatchRepository
```

And here is how I'm using it:

```js
async getSummonerStats(account, season) {
  this.matchRepository.season = season
  const globalStats = await this.matchRepository.globalStats(account.puuid)
  const gamemodeStats = await this.matchRepository.gamemodeStats(account.puuid)
  const roleStats = await this.matchRepository.roleStats(account.puuid)
  // Check if all roles are in the array
  const roles = ['TOP', 'JUNGLE', 'MIDDLE', 'BOTTOM', 'SUPPORT']
  for (const role of roles) {
    if (!roleStats.find(r => r.role === role)) {
      roleStats.push({
        count: 0,
        losses: 0,
        role,
        wins: 0
      })
    }
  }
  const championStats = await this.matchRepository.championStats(account.puuid, 5)
  const championClassStats = await this.matchRepository.championClassStats(account.puuid)
  const mates = await this.matchRepository.mates(account.puuid)

  return {
    global: globalStats[0],
    league: gamemodeStats,
    role: roleStats.sort(Helpers.sortTeamByRole),
    class: championClassStats,
    mates,
    champion: championStats,
  }
}
```

How can it be this bad ? I'm using a 5$ VPS but it was really fast with 30k documents in the database. I don't understand how it turned so slow with "only" 70k more documents.

Comment: Indexes play a key role in making your queries fast. Have you defined any indexes on the fields being using in the aggregation? Indexes defined on the fields used in the `$match` and `$sort` stages early in the aggregation pipeline can be used for performance improvement. See this relevant info in the documentation: [Pipeline Operators and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance).

Comment: Currently I only have index on gameId and summoner_puuid fields. But even with a simple query when I only match the summoner_puuid (which is an index), it takes 600ms (instead of like 20ms before).
Here is the query: https://pastebin.com/gBPf0saY